# What is 이서 and what is the structure behind it?

Tags: grammar

Here is a short quote from TTMIK's iyagi #23:

> 현우: 다 경은 씨처럼 친구가 없는 사람들.

> 경은: 아니요. 두 **명이서** 온 사람들도 있어요.

What is this "이서" and how does it work? My gut feeling is it has something to do with the state-of-being 이다, but does not follow the conjugational rules to my knowledge (would be 이라서/이어서).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(이)서 is a particle indicating number as the agent of an action.  It is used after a word indicating number of people.  이서 comes after a consonant-ending syllable (둘이서) and 서 after vowel-ending one (혼자서).

- 혼자서 = by oneself. 그는 혼자서 싸워야 했다 = He had to fight by himself.
- 둘이서 / 두 명이서 = in twos. 둘이서 하면 쉽다 = It's easier if two people do it.
- 셋이서 / 세 명이서 = in threes.  세 명이서 온 손님 = Customers who came in threes.

아니요. 두 명이서 온 사람들도 있어요 = No. There are also those who came in twos.

Answer (score 0):

이 in 이서 is 파생접미사(derived suffix) which means doing something together and 서 is 보조사(auxiliary postional particle). The combined form '이서' works as a 주격조사 (postional particle for nominative)

Reference:
https://www.kci.go.kr/kciportal/ci/sereArticleSearch/ciSereArtiView.kci?sereArticleSearchBean.artiId=ART002020505

Comment: could you say what it means, or give some examples?